# TypeError: data must be list or dict-like in CUDF

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cudf

I am implementing CUDF to speed up my python process. Firstly, I import CUDF and removed multiprocessing code, and initialize variables with CUDF. After changing into CUDF it gives a dictionary error.

How I can remove these loops to make effective implementation?

**Code**

```
import more_itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
from os import cpu_count
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
import os
import gc
from tqdm import tqdm
import cudf

gc.collect()
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
import logging

mpl_logger = logging.getLogger('matplotlib')
mpl_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

with open(Path(__file__).parent / "ageDB.json", "r") as f:
    identities = json.load(f)

positives = cudf.DataFrame()

for value in tqdm(identities.values(), desc="Positives"):
    positives = positives.append(cudf.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(value, 2), columns=["file_x", "file_y"]),
                                 ignore_index=True)

positives["decision"] = "Yes"
print(positives)

samples_list = list(identities.values())
negatives = cudf.DataFrame()


######################====================Functions=============##############

def compute_cross_samples(x):
    return cudf.DataFrame(itertools.product(*x), columns=["file_x", "file_y"])

####################################
if Path("positives_negatives.csv").exists():
    df = cudf.read_csv("positives_negatives.csv")
else:
    for combos in tqdm(more_itertools.ichunked(itertools.combinations(identities.values(), 2), cpu_count())):
        for cross_samples in (compute_cross_samples, combos):
            negatives = negatives.append(cross_samples)

negatives["decision"] = "No"
negatives = negatives.sample(positives.shape[0])
df = cudf.concat([positives, negatives]).reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv("positives_negatives.csv", index=False)

df.file_x = "deepface/tests/dataset/" + df.file_x
df.file_y = "deepface/tests/dataset/" + df.file_y
```

**Tracback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ensemble-Face-Recognition.py", line 36, in <module>
    positives = positives.append(cudf.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(value, 2), columns=["file_x", "file_y"]),
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/rapids-0.17/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/rapids-0.17/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cudf/core/dataframe.py", line 289, in __init__
    raise TypeError("data must be list or dict-like")
TypeError: data must be list or dict-like
```

Answer (score 0):

itertools.combinations returns a generator, so you need to explicitly call list to get a list-like value

```
cudf.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(value, 2)) . . .
```

As an aside, I'm not sure if this is the case in cudf, but in pandas, it is much faster to create a list of dataframes and concatenate them at the end then it is to create an empty dataframe and then to continually append to it. Your loop continuously sets  positives to an appended dataframe.

Comment: I was going to suggest this issue, but on testing I found that plain `pandas` is ok with a generator input.  `cudf` might be different though.

Comment: positives = positives.append(cudf.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(value, 2), columns=["file_x", "file_y"]),
TypeError: list() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Almost I wasted two months on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting your last comment:

```
positives = positives.append(cudf.DataFrame(
   list(itertools.combinations(value, 2), columns=["file_x", "file_y"]), 

TypeError: list() takes no keyword arguments
```

Because of how you pair (), `columns` is taken as an argument to `list`, not to `DataFrame`.

Comment: Sorry, literally I did not understand your point. the code is the same as above. Could please tell me how to resolve it please?

Comment: Correct the use of `()`